# Codeigniter: Taking 4 similar methods and making them 1 (routing and loading views)

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Scenario**

- 4 types of legal agreements, pulled from the same table in the database
- Each type differentiated by a type id (look up table)
- 1 legal agreement controller

**What I think I have to do**

- 1 method for each type, which loads it's own view with $data variable
- $data filled with that method's specific database call (from a model, of course)
- So: 4 methods in index, 4 separate views, 4 separate URLS (that I can control to be route friendly)

**What I WANT to do**

- 1 index method that accepts an agreement type id (must be routeable, so that legalagreements/1 = legal/termsofservice OR = /termsofservice)
- index MUST be able to send $data variable to the view
- index works off of switch statement
- 1 view (if possible, as all the columns from the table will be the same no matter what is being loaded, and I would be passing it an legalagreement object)

**Where I need help**

- How to use 1 method with the desired routing and still pass it `$data` (`legalagreements/index/1 => legal/termsofservice`)
- How to call said method with a very unique URL (`routes['legal/(:num)'`] = `'legalagreements/index/$1'` ? EXCEPT anyone typing that URL will not know that 1 = termsofservice)

Comment: You tried something? Remember, SO is not a code-writing service. You need to show us some efforts/code done. You should read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JP.Aulet I wasn't asking for written code. I was asking for a general direction to look in as I was having trouble even googling the concept. I actually figured it out, got 1 view, 1 controller, and 1 method outputting 4 different pages based on 1 table column's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general answer I was looking for:

1) Routes:

$route['desiredpagename'] => 'legalagreements/index/1" (or 2 or 3 or 4)

So 4 routes total, 1 for each type possiblity.

2) Controller:

Index ($legal_agreement_type_id) has a case statement that populates generic page data based on type id. The important information comes from the database. Routes make the URL pretty.

3) View:

All variables are the same no matter which page is rendered, therefore 1 view serves all 4 pages.